# System.Net.WebException "Unable to connect to remote server" when calling a WCF service from a WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http, iis

I am writing a service that will allow our products to communicate to one another, from one customer to another. The service basically has a Send method and Receive method, where Send is called from one product, and Receive is called from within Send, which invokes it on the other product.

I'm receiving the said exception in the question title. The service works fine when I call it directly, using the same code, it appears to only be failing when called from within the WCF service.

Here is the code in my `Send` method.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void Send()
{
    var binding     = new WebHttpBinding();
    var endpoint    = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/instance2/service.svc");
    var factory     = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, endpoint);
    var dtoFactory  = new DTOFactory();
    var outgoingDTO = dtoFactory.Create(obj1, obj2, obj3);

    factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebScriptEnablingBehavior());

    binding.SendTimeout  = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
    binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);

    var service = factory.CreateChannel();

    using (var scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)service))
    {
        service.Receive(outgoingDTO);
    }
}
```

The service is hosted in IIS on both ends, so I know that when Receive is called, it is being called under the application pool account, not a Windows account with a session. I've attempted to run my application pool under my administrator account, just to rule this out, but the same error still persists.

This is all on the same machine, just two separate instances of our product. Is there anything special I need to do when calling another WCF service from within a WCF service, when both are hosted in IIS?

Both services use the same exact configuration. WebHttpBinding, the same IService interface, and the same ServiceHostFactory. (Which just adjusts MaxReceivedMessageSize to allow for larger requests).

The exception in the title is actually the inner exception of the following.

```
{"There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/instance2/service.svc/Receive that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."}
```

Inner exception:

```
{"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888"}
```

I have verified I can call the service directly (not from another WCF service) and it works just fine.

Comment: Where is that :8888 port coming from?

Comment: I'm assuming it is `Socket.LocalEndPoint.Port` at a lower level since WCF uses `HttpWebRequest` with a `WebHttpBinding`, but not from our code. That message is part of the inner `System.Net.WebException`.

Comment: Not a firewall / proxy in your machine-wide proxy-cfg?